# Did Vivekananda say "God does not create man in his image; man creates God in his image"?

Tags: gods, identification-request, vivekananda

[This document](http://www.hinduacademy.org/files/Lakhani-CaveHinduismandHumanism.pdf) says that:

> Swami vivekananda had said that "God  does  not  create  man  in  his 
>   image;  man  creates  God  in his image.  If  we  were camels  we 
>   would  have conjured  up a  super camel in  the  sky."

Now I understand the meaning of the above sentence, but I am trying to find this quote from Vivekananda's works from [publications of Belur Math](https://belurmath.org/online-reading-room/) or at [Complete works of Vivekananda from Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda) etc, but I am not able to find it. Can somebody please tell me, where has Vivekananda said this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most relevant quote I find similar to that:

[The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 3/Lectures and Discourses/One Existence Appearing as Many](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_3/Lectures_and_Discourses/One_Existence_Appearing_as_Many):

> God Himself is your image. "God created man after His own image." That is wrong. Man creates God after his own image. That is right. Throughout the universe we are creating gods after our own image. We create the god and fall down at his feet and worship him; and when this dream comes, we love it!

And quote similar to the next line "If we were camels we would have conjured up a super camel in the sky." :

[The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 3/Bhakti-Yoga/Incarnate Teachers and Incarnation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_3/Bhakti-Yoga/Incarnate_Teachers_and_Incarnation)

> There is a story of an ignorant man who was asked to make an image of the God Shiva, and who, after days of hard struggle, manufactured only the image of a monkey. So whenever we try to think of God as He is in His absolute perfection, we invariably meet with the most miserable failure, **because as long as we are men, we cannot conceive Him as anything higher than man.** The time will come when we shall transcend our human nature and know Him as He is; but as long as we are men, we must worship Him in man and as man. Talk as you may, try as you may, you cannot think of God except as a man.

By reading those paragraphs I hope we understand what Swami Vivekananda preached.